# My query said database is not selected even when my database is already selected in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm getting error like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tenants WHERE ic='123456789'
```

No database selected.

Why it says no database selected if I have already selected my database. 
Here is my php code:

```
require "../config/database.php";

$error_text = "Oops! This is a registered identification number! Please check in the tenants list.";

// checking ic already exists
$sql="SELECT * FROM tenants WHERE ic='$ic' ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if($error_mysql){
        echo $error_mysql;
    }

return ($result) ? $error_text : "valid";`
```

Here is my database.php code:

```
/* Define your data to access MySQL database */
    define("REG_USER", "root");                     // your username
    define("REG_SERVER", "localhost");                      // your host
    define("REG_PASSWORD", "");                 // your password
    define("REG_DATABASE", "rsystem");                  // your database

/* Variables */
    $error_exists = false;
    $error_mysql = "";

    /* Connection to DB */
    /* Constants, that defined in action.php, are used */
    $conn = mysqli_connect(REG_SERVER, REG_USER, REG_PASSWORD, REG_DATABASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        $error_mysql = ("Error connecting to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") ". mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like no database with that name exists or you do not have permission to use that database.

Comment: `I have already select my database` What makes you think so?

Comment: Where are you returning this error ? `return $error_mysql;` ?

Comment: in  $conn = mysqli_connect(REG_SERVER, REG_USER, REG_PASSWORD, REG_DATABASE); i have already define my database @u_mulder

Comment: i have double check my database name @arkascha

Comment: If it fails to connect in database.php, what do you actually expect to happen in your main code?

Comment: You defined that you __want to connect__ to your database, but that doesn't mean you __really connect__ to it. See the difference?

Comment: I have tested with same code as defined above it's working fine.

Comment: You `return` an error string from `database.php` to the `require` in your main code, and then ignore it, don't display it anywhere, and still try to execute a query against the database

Comment: oh it should be 'echo $error_mysql;' @AlokPatel

Comment: if it fails im expecting that it gives an error not the 'no database selected' @MarkBaker

Comment: did you run the code?is it working? @krunalnerikar

Comment: Yes. it's working in my system.

Comment: Why would it give you the error..... you're ignoring any error that it might give you..... you're `return`ing the error, and then discarding that returned value without ever doing anything with it.... `$error_mysql = ("Error connecting to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") ". mysqli_connect_error());
        return $error_mysql;` what does your main code do with this `return`ed string?

Comment: but as krunal said my code is running in his system so how it can be like that? @MarkBaker

Comment: @krunalnerikar so why in my system it fail tu run?

Comment: @miorfarhan - you tell me.... modify your code to actually display `$error_mysql` and see what it says!

Comment: It runs because it doesn't get an error, so it doesn't matter that it's not doing anything with the returned value.

Comment: BTW, the way you're checking if `$ic` is valid is not correct. `mysqli_query()`  only returns `false` if it gets an error, but a `SELECT` that doesn't find any matching rows is not an error. You should use `return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ? $error_text : "valid";`

Comment: i edited have my code like above @MarkBaker

Comment: still same @Barmar

Comment: That wasn't supposed to fix the problem, so of course it's still the same. It was a reminder for something you need to fix **after** you solve this problem.

Comment: You should test and print `$error_mysql` **before** you try to call `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: oh okay thanks @Barmar

Comment: I can't think of any reason for "No database selected" except that you have the wrong database name in `REG_DATABASE`.

Comment: me too because at the login pages, im using the same code here and its working @Barmar

Comment: Put `var_dump(REG_DATABASE)` in the main script, to make sure you're loading the correct `database.php`.

Comment: if you database is online then you can not access without password, Error is you access your database without password included request while your database is password protected.

Comment: finally success, the same code but I created a new function.i dont know what is the error before btw thanks @Barmar

Comment: problem solved.im using local thanks btw @ShaileshLimbadiya